# jquery tablesorter not working for two tables on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tablesorter

I have two tables. first table is a main table with 20 columns. among those 20 columns the 17 th column has a button on each row of the main table. On the click of this button a dialogue box appears that display a table of 8 columns with respective records.

The tablesorter is applied for both the tables and the necessary js files are also included.

Issue 1:
The table can be sorted in both directions but the asc and desc icons for the main table are not changed when click on the headers upto column 8.

Issue 2:
When clicked on the headers of the dialogue box table the sorting takes place for both the tables but the main table is sorted in ascending order and the table in the dialogue box is sorted in descending order. For any column the sorting can be done only once.

Please tell me if anything is missing in including the js files. Cannot paste the code here.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/so_style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/so_utils.js"></script>
<script src='dwr/engine.js'></script>
<script src='dwr/util.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css"
    type="text/css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="print, projection, screen" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://malsup.github.io/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
<!-- added for sorting -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script> 

Code:

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#main-table").tablesorter({        
        headers: {
            17: { sorter: false },             
            18: { sorter: false },
            19: { sorter: false },            
            20: { sorter: false } 
        } 
    }); 

}); 

// for the dialog box

 $( ".dialogbox" ).dialog({
                     autoOpen: false,
                     width: '700',
                     resizable: false,
                     modal: true,
                     close: function() {

                         $('#main-table').addClass('tablesorter');
                         $("#main-table").tablesorter({        
        headers: {
            17: { sorter: false },             
            18: { sorter: false },
            19: { sorter: false },            
            20: { sorter: false } 
        } 
    }); 
                     }
              });


// function call onclick of button
  function showData(customerId) {        
              var editId = "dialogbox-" + customerId;        
              $( "#"+editId ).dialog( "option", "title", "Show Data" );       
              $( "#"+editId ).dialog("open");            
              $('#main-table').removeClass('tablesorter');             
              $('#main-table').css("cursor" , "default"); 
              $('#dialogbox-table').addClass('tablesorter');
              $("#dialogbox-table").tablesorter({
                  headers: { 9: {                           
                          sorter: false 
                      }, 
                      10: {                          
                          sorter: false 
                      }
                  }     

              }); }
}
```

The code for dialog box table

```
 <div class="dialog" style="display: none" id="dialogbox-${Id of the saved rowdata in main table}">
        <span>
        <input class="button" type="button" name="Add" value='Add' onclick="addData('${Id of the saved rowdata in main table}')" /></span>
        <table id="dialogbox-table" class="tablesorter">
        <thead>
        <tr class="tBackground">
        <th class="tHeader"><b>Col 1</b> </td>
        <th class="tHeader"><b>Col 2</b> </td>
        <th class="tHeader"><b>Col 3</b> </td>
        <th class="tHeader"><b>Col 4</b> </td>
        <th class="tHeader"><b>Col 5</b> </td>
        <th class="tHeader"><b>Col 6</b> </td>
        <th class="tHeader"><b>Col 7</b> </td>
        <td class="tHeader" colspan="2"><b>Col 8</b></td>
        </tr>
        </thead>                   
        <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${List}" var="bean">
        <tr>
        <td class="tRow"> data </td>
        <td class="tRow"> data </td>
        <td class="tRow"> data </td>
        <td class="tRow"> data </td>
        <td class="tRow"> data </td>
        <td class="tRow"> data </td> 
        <td class="tRow"> data </td>
        <td class="tRow"><input class="button" type="button" name="Delete" value='Delete'
        onclick="deleteData(some parameters)/></td>
        <td class="tableRow">
        <input class="button" type="button" name="modify" value='Edit'
        onclick="modifyData(some parameters)"></td>
        </tr>
        <c:set var="countExtras" value="${countExtras + 1}" />
        </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: show your code for how you initialize tableshorter

Comment: I have added the code for initialize tablesorter

Comment: Is the dialog table the same as the main table? Would you share the HTML (minus the sensitive data) as well? Also, what version of tablesorter are you using?

Comment: The version is 2.0.5b.. The dialog table and the main table are different

Comment: Can we handle such a scenario using tablesorter ?